# QGIS - Raster Layer and Roads - Calculating Pole of Inaccessibility

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a TIFF raster that represents landcover called `Forest` with a value of `1` for landcover and `0` for no data.

I also have GPKG polyline layer `Roads` which is an extract of Highways from OSM.
I need to find the point where the `Forest=1` that is farthest from a road.

I know from a previous question I asked that the `Pole of Inaccessibility` may be the best way to do this.

I have converted the raster to a vector and ran the `Split with Lines` tool but it keeps failing. I have tried repairing the geometry to no avail.

I have also tried converting the `Roads` to a raster with the same resolution and using the `Raster Calculator` to either add or multiple them together however, either way, I get a patchy raster that just covers parts of the roads layer.
I need to find the point within the landcover layers with a value of `1` that’s farthest from a road.

[image]

EDIT:
Below result:
[image]

Comment: Ensure forest CRS is projected not geographic (reproject to temp forest raster if required). Rasterize your roads layer, set output to have fixed value of 1 and nodata=0 and same CRS, extent and cellsize as forest. Run Proximity (raster distance) tool on roads raster with target pixels = 1 (roads).  Use raster calculator to multiply forest raster by road distance raster, output will be distance to roads for forest pixels.

Comment: When mentioning a previous Q&A please always provide a link to it.

Comment: @user2856 - That worked, thank you. Just wondering is there a process I could use so that the areas (like the blue circle above) aren't part of the distance calculation? Essentially I need the distance to almost 'start again' from the edge of these blank areas.

Comment: You will have to burn those areas into your roads raster so they are treated the same as a road.